# sqlachemy excute query slower than run query normal

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have use flask 1.1.2, sqlachemy 1.3.18 and flask-sqlalchemy 2.4.4 for query in db Postgres 12.3, But I had one issue when use query data from db via query builder, it take slower 10 -20 times than excute this query (generate from builder) direct via pgadmin or anyelse tool database, although this same db same query. Here my code:

**base_model.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Base(db.Model):
  __abstract__ = True

  def __init__(self, data):
    for key, item in data.items():
        setattr(self, key, item)

  @classmethod
  def get_all_per_column(cls, column, order=None):
    column = getattr(cls, column, None)

    query = cls.query.with_entities(cls.__mapper__.primary_key[0], column).distinct()
    if order:
        query = query.order_by(order)
    else:
        query = query.order_by(column)
    res = query.all()
    return res
```

**a_model.py**

```
class A(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'table_a'

   @classmethod
   def query_join_and_filter_many_tables_in_db(cls, filters=None):
       query = cls.query.with_entities(<list column in table a>, <list column in table b>, <list column table c>, ...)
       query = query.join(table_b)
       query = query.join(table_c)
       .... # Join about ~10 table is here
       query = query.filter(<>)
       list_result = query.offset(0).limit(20).all()

       # Get full query
       # full_query = query.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
       return list_result
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from base_mode import db

Base = declarative_base()
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
engine = create_engine(os.getenv('DB_URI'), echo_pool=True)
DBSession.remove()
DBSession.configure(bind=engine, autoflush=True, expire_on_commit=False)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
db.init_app(app)

#### use check time excute ####
@event.listens_for(Engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement,
                          parameters, context, executemany):
    conn.info.setdefault('query_start_time', []).append(time.time())
    logger.debug("Start Query: %s", statement)


@event.listens_for(Engine, "after_cursor_execute")
def after_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement,
                         parameters, context, executemany):
    total = time.time() - conn.info['query_start_time'].pop(-1)
    logger.debug("Query Complete!")
    logger.debug("Total Time: %f", total)
```

And here my log:

```
2020-11-26 14:27:25 - p13 - (myapp.sqltime:84) - DEBUG: Start Query: <QUERY #if bring it to db tools this query run very fast> 
2020-11-26 14:27:25 - p13 - (myapp.sqltime:91) - DEBUG: Query Complete!
2020-11-26 14:27:25 - p13 - (myapp.sqltime:92) - DEBUG: Total Time: 143.593255 #in second
```

but **same query** when run on db tool take only 2s.

When I run with [sqlalchemy-profiled](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/performance.html#code-profiling). I had log below:

**Run full query builder log**

```
345197 function calls (333631 primitive calls) in 144.396 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.000    0.000  143.366   71.683 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3498(__iter__)
        2    0.000    0.000  143.338   71.669 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3523(_execute_and_instances)
        5    0.000    0.000  143.273   28.655 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:946(execute)
        2    0.000    0.000  143.267   71.633 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:296(_execute_on_connection)
        2    0.000    0.000  143.267   71.633 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1082(_execute_clauseelement)
        5    0.000    0.000  143.183   28.637 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1189(_execute_context)
        9  143.167   15.907  143.167   15.907 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
        7    0.000    0.000  143.162   20.452 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:592(do_execute)
        1    0.000    0.000  142.788  142.788 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3325(all)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.818    0.818 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3715(count)
      112    0.001    0.000    0.628    0.006 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py:222(generate)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.583    0.583 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3471(scalar)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.583    0.583 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3439(one)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.583    0.583 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3403(one_or_none)
4739/4092    0.016    0.000    0.409    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:880(__get__)
       61    0.001    0.000    0.372    0.006 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2087(join)
```

**Run with raw query use execute:**

```
    16935 function calls (15669 primitive calls) in 153.674 seconds
       Ordered by: cumulative time
       ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
            1    0.000    0.000  153.620  153.620 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2217(execute)
            1    0.000    0.000  153.603  153.603 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:946(execute)
            1    0.000    0.000  153.603  153.603 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1164(_execute_text)
            1    0.000    0.000  153.603  153.603 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1189(_execute_context)
            1    0.000    0.000  153.592  153.592 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:592(do_execute)
            1  153.592  153.592  153.592  153.592 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
            1    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.052 <string>:1(<lambda>)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.052 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:412(compile)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.052 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:478(_compiler)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.052 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:527(__init__)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.052 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:274(__init__)
          6/1    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.052 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:349(process)
        823/1    0.004    0.000    0.052    0.052 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py:86(_compiler_dispatch)
         14/1    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.052 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:2045(visit_select)
           14    0.001    0.000    0.035    0.002 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:2127(<listcomp>)
          159    0.002    0.000    0.034    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:1799(_label_select_column)
         14/1    0.000    0.000    0.020    0.020 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:2233(_compose_select_body)
         14/1    0.000    0.000    0.019    0.019 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:2252(<listcomp>)
```

It take to 153s for execute query. (Although run directly with tool only have  take 2s)

Thanks for help!

**PS:** And one thing, when I *clone new db with full data* from old db, then point my code to new db, this code work fast as direct query. I restart old db then point code again => still running as slowly as before (damn it)(angry).

**UPDATE:**
when I check db by `select * from pg_stats_activity` a get all this query execute via code have state is active (headbang)

**UPDATE 2**
here explain analyze for same query in 2 same db (clone)
[Slow query](https://explain.depesz.com/s/TRdFS)
[Fast query](https://explain.depesz.com/s/fIyM)

Anyone can explain this for me. And how can fix it (without clone newdb).

**FINAL UPDATED:** I had optimized this query by 2 steps and I had reduces excute time down ~20x times.

Comment: Try printing the query in your python code before executing it. It should give you the sql commands so you could check that the queries are really identical. I sincerely doubt they are.

Comment: How many items are you returning? If there's millions I'd imagine there will be a ton of overhead.

Comment: @PetrBlahos I had print query and run it in db tool. And have result the same.

Comment: @Peter In query have offset limit. But total row without limit only have about 500 records

Comment: It would be helpful see the DDL for the table, the model code, and the SQL that you used to query directly.  And the number of records in the table.  Then we can verify that SQLA generates the same SQL, and try to reproduce the behaviour locally.

Comment: @snakecharmerb cause of security I can't share DDL or SQL. But I try description model code above. You can imagne 1 SQL have 10 table join and filter. And I use SQL generate by SQLA (get from log above) or use code `query.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})` to get full query to check directly on other tools.

Comment: From the profile data, it looks like  it spends all the time in psycopg2 - do you seem the same behaviour if the execute the sql in psycopg2 directly?

Comment: Can you test this with just a single cursor object in the main file and then execute a simple statement with the cursor object, like a select * from pg_stat_activity? Does this take time ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I had update log but it same slow at psycopg2

Comment: @RajVerma other query execute still fast. Only slow at this query

Comment: Any chance your test code connection/session has some uncommitted changes, and therefore the "locking" mechanism creates some overhead?

Comment: @van maybe, but how can I fix it? When I use  `select * from pg_stat_activity` I can see some connect with query in status active.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE for your query? You could use an obfuscated version on https://explain.depesz.com And something else, what is your database configuration for join_collapse_limit ? SHOW join_collapse_limit;

Comment: @FrankHeikens had update explain analyze (same query)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these obfuscated queries are not the same. I can't find any filter in the fast query, that looks like this one (from the slow query):

> Join Filter:
> (juliet_quebec(yankee_uniform((quebec_foxtrot.four_three)::text),
> 'foxtrot_whiskey'::text,
> ''whiskey_two'([\hotel_quebec]+)$'juliet_foxtrot''::text)))

That looks like a regular expression. Could you dig into this? And compare it with the original slow and fast queries?

india_three is also consuming a lot of time, each seq scan is fast, but it's done in many loops (198602, twice).

And is there any way that you could show us the real (obfuscated) query?

Comment: Thank you! Here obfuscated query  https://explain.depesz.com/s/JbFK. I checked data in 2 db: 2 db same struct, fast db have more data than slow db (~500 records in all table appear in query)

Comment: can u have some ideal to resolve problem :-?